# What are the best practices for accessing a kubernetes pod with sftp or ssh?

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployed a wordpress pod on Kubernetes and I want to be able to use `sftp` or `ssh` to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers is a bit different from whole Virtual Machines. With containers you typically only run a single process - your app. Unless your app is a ssh-daemon or an FTP server, it does not support sftp or ssh protocol. It is common for apps in Kubernetes only to use HTTP.

That said, it is possible to run one-off commands in containers using `kubectl exec`, see [Get a Shell to a Running Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/)

> so what are the best practices for managing the files of a webserver type pod? You have to publish the files and their updates

There are two common way to do this:

- Copy the files to a Dockerfile and build a new container image (this also contains the web server).
- Upload the files to a Bucket, e.g. [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) and let the server serve those files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ok, so what are the best practices for managing the files of a webserver type pod? You have to publish the files and their updates.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I explore this solutions